# Decoding nested JSON when the keys at the lowest level are the same

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, dictionary

I need your help on decoding this piece of JSON

```
{
    "json": {
        "firstItem": {
            "key": "key",
            "value": "data"
        },
        "secondItem": {
            "key": "key",
            "value": "data"
        },
        "thirdItem": {
            "key": "key",
            "value": "data"
        },.......... //All of the data, which is a lot, comes like this
    }
}
```

I want to be able to decode this data, but can't figure out a way without having to write too much code because there are a lot of items. Is it possible to be able to decode this JSON maybe into a nesting of dictionaries, or even better into an array of item objects with just key and value attributes? Thanks in advance

Comment: try to use codable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Swifts structs combined with [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) we can achieve very clean and nice solution to the problem.

#### Declare Item struct

helper struct will be useful when retrieving values from each item contained within the json dictionary

```swift
struct Item: Codable {
    let key: String
    let value: String
}
```

#### Decode the JSON

now, considering the json is a string value, you can decode it easily with [JSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder)

```swift
let jsonString: String // your json here

guard let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let decoded = try decoder.decode([String: [String: Item]].self, from: data)
    let itemsDict: [String: Item] = decoded["json"] ?? [:]

    // do what you want with the items!
    let firstItem: Item? = itemsDict["firstItem"]
    let items: [Item] = itemsDict.values
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: awesome, great to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

I went old school with my answer:

```
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: [String: [String: Any]]] else { return }
let keyValues = json["json"].map { $0.values.map { ($0["key"]! as! String, $0["value"]!) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom type for your key/value pairs

```
struct KeyValue: Decodable {
    let key: String
    let value: String
}
```

and then decode them into an array like this

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [String: KeyValue]].self, from: data)
    let array = result["json"]?.reduce(into: []) { $0.append($1.value) }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the keys of the nesting json you can simply decode it as a dictionary of items:

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let json: [String: Item]
}
```

---

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    let key, value: String
}
```

---

```
let json = """
{
    "json": {
        "firstItem": {
            "key": "key",
            "value": "data"
        },
        "secondItem": {
            "key": "key",
            "value": "data"
        },
        "thirdItem": {
            "key": "key",
            "value": "data"
        }
    }
}
"""
```

---

```
do {
    let items = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: .init(json.utf8)).json.map(\.value)
    print(items)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

This will print:

> [Item(key: "key", value: "data"), Item(key: "key", value: "data"), Item(key: "key", value: "data")]